Access computed property from a child component, using the composition api
From what I understood, this can be done with refs. But for some reason I always get undefined
this is my parent:
<template>
  <div>
    <child ref="refChild" />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
   import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
   import child from 'child.vue';

   const refChild = ref(null);

   const someValue = computed(() => {
     if(refChild.value !== null)
       console.log(refChild.value.childComputedProp); // undefined
   });
</script>


In Composition API <script setup> the child must explicitely expose its data to the parent via defineExpose({childComputedProp}).  Be wary though, as it's usually not best practice for parent component to directly access data or methods of child component.  Use of v-model or emit/event listener would be better.
